# How to wait for reactive stream completion, similar to Thread.join? (without blockLast or active waiting)

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have reactive stream, but in CLI app, that one terminates immediately, and I cannot find any acceptable solution.

Lets start with easy example. CLI app, we create "long" running daemon thread to simulate similar situation as I experience with reactive streams:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            System.out.println("Start.");
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            System.out.println("Well done!");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    });
    thread.setDaemon(true);
    thread.start();
}
```

if we run this, the app terminates immediately, as there is no non-daemon thread running when the main one is finishing. This example is pretty easy to fix:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            System.out.println("Start.");
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            System.out.println("Well done!");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    });
    thread.setDaemon(true);
    thread.start();
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

Now it's "well done", at least that's what gets printed. Now lets move to reactive streams. Following terminates immediately:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Flux.range(1, 10)
            .zipWith(Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1)))
            .map(Tuple2::getT1)
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```

Ok, I can "fix" this like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Flux.range(1, 10)
            .zipWith(Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1)))
            .map(Tuple2::getT1)
            .doOnNext(System.out::println)
            .blockLast();
}
```

}

but don't want to use side-effect method `doOnNext` or `blockLast`, it does not seem good to me, and I don't have now possibility to use `errorConsumer` and `completeConsumer` available in `subscribe` method. I've seen following being recommended:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Disposable disposable = Flux.range(1, 10)
            .zipWith(Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1)))
            .map(Tuple2::getT1)
            .subscribe(System.out::println);

    while (!disposable.isDisposed()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

and while working with disposable is fine, active waiting is not.

What is the correct solution here to use subscribe and somehow join to "reactive threads"? Or And if `subscribe` ins't the way to go, and I can somehow reformulate it (with all 3 consumers) differently, then how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are describing is that you don't want to use the blocking mechanism of reactor but instead implement a custom blocking mechanism that will do virtually the same thing.

Just use [`blockLast()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#blockLast--), it's totally valid for this situation.

However, if your application is more complex than your example, just make sure that you really only block once and on that main thread!

Comment: thanks for comment, but (as a reactive beginner) I really don't know what you mean by all that. And to be honest the active waiting is accepted answer somewhere here in stackoverflow. The documentation does quite a good job describing individual operators (well sometimes not), but kinda fails to provide overall how-to. Can you show how to do what you recommended? Or how to get all 3 listeners (onNext,onError, onComplete) and block from main thread? As unless I'm really blind, it's not shown anywhere

Comment: I assume you are trying to "act" on the different signals at the end? If so, just add those onNext/onError/onComplete and after that blockLast().

Comment: @MartinMucha I believe that the author wants to say something like this: If what you want is just to wait until the `Flux` finishes emitting, do not reinvent the wheel and just use the `blockLast()` method which is there exactly for this purpose :)